# How to make " " values in SQL Server empty/null instead (many columns)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some 150 columns, and I haven't the faintest clue how to remove these `" "` values. I've seen some solutions for single columns, but since I have so many I would like a solution that does it for every column... not sure if that's possible?

I tried:

```
USE master

UPDATE [master].[dbo].[csvimport] 
SET value = NULL 
WHERE value = " "
```

From what I found researching, but it tells me:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'value'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name ' '.

I've seen:

```
SELECT NULLIF(null_column, 0) AS null_column 
FROM [master].[dbo].[csvimport]
```

But this only works for one column at a time. I'd rather not do this 150 times...

Comment: There is not shortcut here. If you want to update data in columns you have to state what you want to happen for each column. But 150 columns sounds like a pretty unwieldy table.

Comment: The columns are mostly stuff like MONTH 1 MONTH 2 MONTH 3 ... MONTH 150.
Don't ask me why I didn't set it up :P

Comment: Ugh that is painful to work with. You can leverage sys.columns and some dynamic sql but if the names are that consistent I would probably just use excel to help me build my update statements.

Comment: You can make it less painful (or switch to a different pain if you want) by using dynamic SQL and creating the `UPDATE` query by querying `sys.columns`. So you have a script to write your final query, which will still specify columns one by one.

Comment: Oh yeah using excel to help is a good idea, thanks fam I'll try that. I'll look into using dynamic sql as well!

Answer (score 0):

This will result in a bunch of SQL statements to run. or you can cursor it. I was a little confused with your search term of " " which isn't tsql logic.

```
declare @tablename varchar(100) ='[Enter your table name]'

select 'Update '+ @tablename + ' set ' +  quotename(column_name) + '=null where '+  quotename(column_name) + '='' '''
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_NAME = @tablename
```

to help you understand this query run this. The rest is dynamically building SQL around it:

```
select quotename(column_name),*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
```

Comment: added quotename() to handle spaces in column names